# How should I tidy up loose speaker wires?

Tags: wiring, speakers

I have surround sound speakers with the speaker wires going up through the wall. The wire is fixed and doesn't slide in and out the wall.

Now it's time to tidy it up!

- How much loose wire should I leave?
- How can I tidy up the loose wire?

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>Click for larger view</sup>

Comment: Its too late now but you could have mounted the speaker so the wire passed through the hole in the mount.

Comment: @Craig  maybe not.. pretty easy to fish the wire through there using a 12" piece of 14 ga solid wire or even piece of coat hanger..  just make a "c" with a radius that matches the 2 holes, tape the speaker wire on, pull back through.  I little spackle or patching compound will make the hole disappear

Comment: Even if the wires are fixed in the wall it is still possible to push the extra wire through the hole so that the slack bundle is in the wall instead of hanging on the outside.

Answer (score 7):

My first concern here is safety and code compliance.  Ordinary speaker wire is not in-wall-rated.

You need to use CL2 or better, CMR rated cable for in wall use..

CL2R is short for Class 2 Riser  [Site detailing low voltage cable options](http://www.bluejeanscable.com/articles/inwallrating.htm)

[image]  [Link to speaker wire](http://www.bluejeanscable.com/store/speaker/index.htm)

As far as neatness goes, installing a termination panel or a "brush" wall plate would help

[image]

Decora style insert which would mount to a low voltage old work ring [image]

Comment: wow, I'd never heard of a "brush" wall plate. great advice -- thanks.

Comment: The brush wall plates are great.  Alternatively you could get one that has speaker wire clamps to make the speaker easily detachable.